# PS2 keyboard not working on a Windows and Ubuntu dual boot system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, keyboard, multi-boot, ps2

I have a Windows and Ubuntu dual boot system. From yesterday my keyboard is not working in either of the OS. But it works fine while selecting the operating system or installing an operating system.

Is there any way of solving this issue?

- The keyboard is connected via PS2.
- The LED lights on the keyboard are on when the system is powered.

Tested this with another keyboard and the same problem happens.

Comment: Lots more details needed. USB keyboard? Wireless? When do you select, in grub?

Comment: PS2 interfaced keyboard .